# How to detect Swing thread policy violations

Tags: java, debugging, swing, multithreading

I am looking for an automatic way to detect violations of the Swing's single threaded policy in my code.  I'm looking for something along the lines of some AOP code you drop into the VM while the swing app is running and have it log any places where a swing component is modified outside of the EDT.

I'm not an AOP guy but I would imagine creating an AOP proxy around every java.swing.* class which looks like

```
AOP_before(Method m, Object args[]) {
 if (!isEventDispatchThread(Thread.currentThread()) {
  logStack(new RuntimeException("violation!"));
 }

 invoke(m, args);
}
```

Anyone know of a project or utility that does this?

Comment: I've answered a question like this before, and provided AOP code. Any tips for how I go about finding it? I've tried the obvious, Google, and SO search.

Comment: I suggest just keeping a clean separation between code that should that should run on the EDT and that that should not. Try to avoid having classes combining code that should be run on the EDT and code that should be not, even if it looks like a shortcut.

Comment: @mdma, just click your name and you can see the list of questions you've answered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't used this particular one, but this [CheckThreadViolationRepaintManager](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/DetectEventDispatchThreadruleviolations.htm) should do the trick.

It does have the requirement of adding:

```
RepaintManager.setCurrentManager(new CheckThreadViolationRepaintManager());
```

to your code however.

Comment: This one worked pretty good.  I have already found some violations.

Comment: The linked code is based on some earlier work by another guy. The code includes a link to his non-existent blog post; I found a copy on the WaybackMachine and found it to be an interesting read. Here's a link to the permanently[?] archived version of the original author's blog entry on the RepaintManager-based solution. http://web.archive.org/web/20071212214347/http://www.clientjava.com/blog/2004/08/31/1093972473000.html

Answer (score 4):

For posterity's sake, here's a simplified version of the CheckThreadViolationRepaintManager that TofuBeer found.

```
RepaintManager.setCurrentManager(new RepaintManager() {
   public synchronized void addInvalidComponent( JComponent component ) {
     check( component );
     super.addInvalidComponent( component );
   }
   public void addDirtyRegion( JComponent component, int x, int y, int w, int h ) {
     check( component );
     super.addDirtyRegion( component, x, y, w, h );
   }
   private void check( JComponent c ) {
     if( !SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread() && c.isShowing() ) {
        new Throwable("EDT required!").printStackTrace();
     }
   }
});
```

Just call that in your main method and you'll get stacktraces logged whenever components are being changed on non-EDT threads.

Answer (score 3):

I've found a 4 years old blog post describing [some solutions](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/alexfromsun/archive/2006/02/debugging_swing.html), but would be really interested if you find one which detects the most EDT violations. The RepaintManager seems not to be bullet proof in detecting all violations.

Comment: Is it known what kinds of cases the RepaintManager fails to detect?

Comment: These solutions look really good, but more difficult to implement quickly.

Comment: do you still have the link?  The one you provide doesn't work anymore.