# How to check for FX Application threading policy violations

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

An application I'm working with makes heavy use of JavaFX, and I've noticed that we keep getting exceptions of the form mentioned on [this open jdk issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8094788). The issue mentions that the exception can occur when you create nodes off of the FX application thread.

I would like to find any places where FX objects are accessed off the FX thread, but the application is large enough that it's impractical to do this by inspection. I see a [similar question and answer for Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153574/how-to-detect-swing-thread-policy-violations), but haven't been able to track down anything similar for JavaFX. The Swing solution most often mentioned there involved a custom `RepaintManager`, which is a Swing-specific interface.

**So**: *How (if at all) can I find places where code accesses JavaFX objects on threads other than the FX application thread, without manually inspecting all the application's FX code?*

---

**Note**: I am fully aware that it is a bad idea to interact with fx objects off of the fx thread. Once I find violations of the policy, I am also fully aware that I can use `Platform.runLater(()->{/*fx code*/});` to  perform the operations on the fx thread. My question is about *how to find the violations*.

Comment: `Platform.runLater(new Runnable() { @Override public void run() { /* do stuff on the JFX thread */ } });`

Comment: @SnakeDoc: See the added note. I know how to fix threading policy violations when I find them.

Comment: Practically, I don't think there is any way for you to accomplish this.

Comment: Have you tried taking a peak at your app's thread under a profiler? It should give some insight as-to which thread is doing what and when. Maybe not exactly what you're looking for, but could be helpful. JProfiler is great, but Oracle JDK (maybe OpenJDK now too) comes with a free profiler, JVisualVM.

Comment: @SnakeDoc: I'm not sure how best to leverage a profiler to find the info I'm looking for. I suppose I could periodically force thread dumps and take a peak at whether any threads are somewhere in an FX stack, but the chances of catching offenders in this way seems haphazard at best (what if a thread only spends 1% of it's cpu time in the FX stack? enough to cause bugs, but not likely to be caught with a snapshot).

Comment: I haven't tried myself, but perhaps FindBugs would points out some offenders?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not ideal, but one solution is to put a conditional breakpoint in `java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(String name,boolean resolve)`, with the condition:

```
name.startsWith("javafx") && 
    !Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("JavaFX Application Thread")
```

Then whenever new classes get loaded from a javafx package, you can check whether the classes are being loaded on the FX thread. It certainly won't catch all violations, but when a thread uses FX code that causes the loading of an FX class that hasn't been used before it will let you know by pausing the violating thread.

(It would be nice if `!javafx.application.Platform.isFxApplicationThread()` could be added to the breakpoint condition, but in Eclipse Luna I'm having trouble getting that to work.)

Note also that not every time you hit this is an actual violation- a class can be loaded without an actual object of that class being instantiated and/or interacted with. Ex, if the following constructor was called from a non-FX thread, it might set off the breakpoint despite not being dangerous:

```
public class MyClass{
    Label l = null; //Loading & instantiating MyClass loads
                    // the Label class, but doesn't necessarily
                    // violate the FX threading policy

    public MyClass(){

    }
}
```

The solution is better than nothing, however (I've already found one actual violation with it).

Comment: Try FindBugs, I'd be interested in knowing if it catches this type of issue (since it's likely rather common).

Answer (score 0):

I've personally found conditional breakpoints in Eclipse extremely slow to execute. Note newer versions of Eclipse do allow !Platform.isFxApplicationThread().

Another approach is possible using byte-buddy (dynamic code modification library, other libraries are available...). This is effectively the same thing, but for whatever reason runs significantly faster.

There are lots of places you could check but I've found `com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper#markDirty()` a good focal point for most JavaFX changes.

```
public class JavaFxThreadValidator {

    public static void install() {
        Instrumentation instrumentation = ByteBuddyAgent.install();
        new AgentBuilder.Default().type(ElementMatchers.named("com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper"))
                .transform((builder, typeDescription, classLoader, module, domain) -> builder
                        .method(ElementMatchers.named("markDirty"))
                        .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(MethodInterceptor.class)))
                .installOn(instrumentation);
    }

    public static class MethodInterceptor {
        private MethodInterceptor() {
            // static util class
        }

        public static void intercept() {
            if (!Platform.isFxApplicationThread()) {
                // report error...
            }
        }
    }
}
```